# How can I ignore properties of a component using Fluent Nhibernate's AutoPersistenceModel?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate AutoMappings to map my entities, including a few component objects.
One of the component objects includes a property like the following:

```
public string Value 
{ 
  set _value = value; 
}
```

This causes an NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: "Could not find a getter for property 'Value'..."

I want to ignore this property.

I tried creating an IAutoMappingOverride for the component class but I couldn't use AutoMapping<>.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Value) for the same reason.
"The property or indexer 'MyComponent.Value' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor"

I've also looked at IComponentConvention but can't see anyway of altering the mappings with this convention.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Reveal.Member<Owner, object> ("Value")`.
```

Eg

```
mapping.IgnoreProperty(Reveal.Member<Owner, object> ("Value")
```

Reveal.Member can be used anywhere Fluent NHibernate expects an expression. This can be used to expose private/protected properties and fields.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chris. Fortunately the model has since evolved so I don't need the write only property any more. I'll test out your answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that works pretty well. A couple of points though: 1 - IgnoreProperty expects Reveal.Member<EntityType, object>("Value") - not string; 2 - It still requires a private get accessor on the property.

Comment: After updating FluentNHibernate to v1.3, this unfortunately no longer works - the mapping is not ignored and the following error is generated: NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException : The following types may not be used as proxies: method get_Value should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'

Answer (score 1):

You can use OverrideAll() in your mapping file.  If you don't know the type that it will be a member of, then you need to use this version specify the member as a string.  Here's the example from the [Fluent Nhibernate Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Ignoring_properties).

```
.OverrideAll(map =>  
{  
  map.IgnoreProperty("YourProperty");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the override to work if you add a private Get method to your property.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both a private and protected get accessor but the override won't compile unless the accessor is public.

"The property or indexer cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor"

Comment: Others have had trouble with private backing variables and FNH - I wouldn't use them unless I really, really needed them. I suggest you try declaring the property as "public virtual string Value { get; set; }" in order to get the override working, and then experiment with making the "get" private (I know you can make "set" private, but not sure about "get").

Answer (score 0):

You can add public getter throwing `NotSupportedException` to make compiler happy:

```
public virtual string Value 
{ 
    get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the best option.

Comment: Chris Chilvers answer, using Reveal.Member<Entity, object>("PropertyName") to ignore the property, gives the desired result. No more needless NotSupportedException!

Comment: `Reveal` is not IntelliSense-friendly